# tSNE visualize 2D CNN output features

Tags: neural-networks, tsne

I want to visualize the 2D CNN output features with tSNE, but most methods use FCN output, this is 1-D feature, for exmaple in https://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/cnnembed/, but my problem is that I do not have the FCN layer, my output is 2D feature, I do not think that flatting the 2D to 1D is the best idea, do you have any other idea?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What are your concerns about flattening?

Comment: I mean flatting 2D to 1D will lose the structure(neighborhood information).